# spark dataframe custom udf to return an array

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, dataframe, intervals

sample dataset with single column:

```
5.1,
4.9,
4.7,
4.6,
5,3.
5.4,
4.6,
5,
4.4,
4.9,
5.4,
4.8,
4.8,
4.3,
5.8
```

I want it to be sorted in ascending order first and then select values at intervals and return it as an array.

For example, if the interval = 5, and the sorted dataset is

```
4.3,
4.4,
4.6,
4.6,
4.7,
4.8,
4.8,
4.9,
4.9,
5,
5.1,
5,3.
5.4,
5.4,
5.8
```

It should return `Array(4.3, 4.7, 5, 5.8)`.

Is there any way to do this in an optimistic way?

Thanks in advance
Shakti

this is what i have tried, but not able to get the first value.

```
val interval = 5
val count = df.count() //15
val n = (count/interval).toInt //3
println(s"interval: $interval, count: $count, n: $n")

val window = Window.orderBy("col1")
val sorted =  df.withColumn("rowId", functions.row_number().over(window))
sorted.show()

val sb = new StringBuilder
for (i <- 0 to n) {
  val intervalPoint = interval * i
  println(s"i: $i, intervalPoint: $intervalPoint")
  sb.append(s"rowId == $intervalPoint or ")
}

sb.delete(sb.size - 3, sb.size - 1)
println(s"sb: ${sb.toString()}") //rowId == 0 or rowId == 5 or rowId == 10 or rowId == 15

val intervals = sorted.where(sb.toString()).select("col1").collectAsList()
println(s"intervals: $intervals") //[[4.7], [5.0], [5.8]]
```

as you can see, first it has to be sorted by col and append a row id. hopefully, these two would be done in one scan. and another scan of entire dataset to get the intervals, and that too, i was unable to get the first value. If this has to be applied on several columns, it has to be in a loop, and the no. of scans would increase.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far...

Comment: you don't need spark for that and spark won't perform well for the requirement that you have. A simple local computation using scala should be the better option

Comment: this is just a sample data, actual data could have more records and more columns and i require to get intervals for each of the selected columns separately. I'm not sure if simple scala would be able to handle large datasets. I wanted to use dataframes and if needed udfs

Answer (score 0):

one possible solutions (cleaner) :

lets say you have a **dataframe** 'df' :

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table_1")
sparkSession.sql("select col1 from (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS id, col1 from temp_table_1) y where id%(SOME_INTERVAL) = 0 order by col1").show()
```

Comment: definitely, it is more cleaner, but what about applying the same for more than one col and for large datasets? is there anyway to reduce the number of scans?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by more than one col? Can you provide another dataset with your requirement?
in above method, number of scan on whole table is 1 in subquery. And since this all is in memory, I don't think it matters much.